# Ethernet throttling itself? Wireless is fine. Video of issue included

Tags: ethernet, network-adapter, bandwidth, throttling

https://youtu.be/baV-P00i7CY

I just got internet installed today at my new apartment. I'm connecting using my desktop. When I'm connected directly to the modem I get exactly 14.31 mbps every time. However if I hook up a router and then connect with my desktop through my wireless card I get around 40 mbps. Is something causing this? How can I fix it?

Comment: Need details of your router, how far from router over wired, type of cable used, any firmware upgrades available etc.

Comment: Service provider? Also Type of service, cable, dsl, fios, AT&T etc...??

Comment: I would suspect something horribly wrong with your Ethernet cable. Is it one you made or one you purchased?

Comment: How fast is your actual internet speed? The direct connection might show your actual speed while the wireless connection shows the wireless speed.

Comment: You could have a faulty router also. That seems odd have you tried different ports on your router? Could you please post the model also.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem only has a few possible causes:

- network adapter compatibility issues (which are very uncommon nowadays)
- cabling issue which seems to be the most likely cause;  make sure to try the same cable that you use to connect your router.
- software related issue such as a firewall rule;  try disabling your firewall and any security software

If you still can't find the source of the problem, you should try a different computer to try to clarify if the problem is really with the computer.